# Given a dataset is it possible to decide which curve best fits the data?

Tags: regression

I have a dataset containing weights and heights of 1000 people. I used simple linear regression to arrive at an equation. I wonder why cannot I try to fit an ellipse or a parabola or some curve. Is there is a theory which helps to decide whether a curve or a straight line fits a data.

Comment: Well, an ellipse is not a function, and we try and fit data to functions.

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense unless you define clearly what is meant by "best-fit" for the data.

Comment: This arguably is the domain of statistics, but of course there is some math involved.

Comment: @John Ruby : Nothing prevents you from fitting another kind of curve than a straight line. It is up to you to chose a convenient equation to model the phenomena that you are studying. And it's important as well to clearly define the criteria of fitting, i.e. the mathematical definition of what you call "best fit" convenient for your model. The theory to decide whether a curve or a straight line depends on the context, physical-, modeling-, statistical-,... theories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether
you have a model that
the data should fit.

In your case,
for example,
if the bodies are all
of similar shape,
you might expect that
$weight
\sim a\ height^3
$
for  some $a$.

Therefore
$\log weight
\sim \log a +3\,\log height
$
so a linear plot
of log weight
vs. log height
might be informative.
In particular,
if this does not show
a linear relationship,
it might indicate that
the proposed relationship
does not hold.